# obtain path inside custom plugin

Tags: django, django-cms

I create my first custom plugin using the official documentation of [django cms](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/how_to/custom_plugins.html#the-simplest-plugin)

inside my plugin I have a static and template folder... my static folder has `js` and `CSS` folder inside

inside my template folder, I have other folder and inside this my drawchart.html file

I use this [info](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/how_to/custom_plugins.html#handling-media) to handling my js and CSS file inside the plugin

I have this in my `drawnChart.html` file to obtain the path of my static folder inside my plugin

```
{% load sekizai_tags %}

{% addtoblock "js" %}<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}drawChart/js/chart.js"></script>{% endaddtoblock %}
```

but I obtain this response

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/drawChart/js/chart.js
```

any idea to How obtain this path?

thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Which path are you trying to get?

Comment: Thanks @Paulo I fix the problem , I forgot to include the `{% load static %}` now work `{% load sekizai_tags %}
{% load static %}

{% addtoblock "js" %}
<script src="{% static "js/chart.js" %}" class="showme_chart" data={{ instance.chart_url }}></script>
{% endaddtoblock %}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% load sekizai_tags %}
{% load static %}

{% addtoblock "js" %}
<script src="{% static "js/chart.js" %}" class="showme_chart" data={{ instance.chart_url }}></script>
{% endaddtoblock %}
```